# How to install Apache and PHP by using only packages on FreeBSD?

Tags: apache-2.2, freebsd, installation, php5

Is there a way to install without compiling them through the ports? I installed Apache from packages and it works, but `pkg_add -r php53` doesn't install `mod_php5.so`/`libphp5.so`. I experiment on FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you only have two options:

1. Compile the apache22 port with the php5 option on your server.
2. Compile the apache22 port on a local machine, create your own custom
   package, and install that on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use these commands:

```
# portsnap fetch
# portsnap extract
# portsnap upgrade
# pkg install apache24
# pkg install phpmyadmin
# pkg install php5
```

So everything will be installed successfully right to go ahead.